# Facebook sharer keeps showing 404 on my jekyll blog

Tags: facebook, jekyll, facebook-sharer

I used to have the permalink set as follows:

```
/:categories/:year/:title/
```

But to shorten the link I decided to set it like that:

```
/:title/
```

The strange thing that happens is that although facebook sharer sees the proper link, it does not display it and each click on facebook share button looks like this:

[image]

But when I share it to my timeline, it keeps showing 404 but when clicked it directs to the right page.

It looks like a facebook issue, since twitter sharer does not seem to have such problems.

Have you ever encountered such issue and know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch new scrape information

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

solves the issue